# Bell chart with PHP

Tags: php, graph

I am looking for a way to create a bell curve in PHP.
I have tried with JPgraph, and a lined scatter graph, but I have no idea how to align it to a bell curve.

Honestly I've never used a bell curve and I've got to make one which takes 3 inputs for a charity organization, but i have no idea how it work, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a quite good understanding of PHP and if you could possibly paste the code, I am almost certain that i would find a way to understand it.

Comment: Bell curve is a [normal (or Gaussian) distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

Comment: @Kbo Well it worked kind of - because you can not see the bottom text, as there are 1.000 inputs it just overwrites the text besides it

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes i knew that, but i still have no idea how to make that :(

Answer (score 0):

Simple bell curve

```
for ($x = -M_PI; $x <= M_PI; $x += (M_PI / 20)) {
    echo sprintf('%+01.2f => %01.8f' . PHP_EOL, $x, (cos($x) + 1) / 2);
}
```

But please explain your three inputs: that would be expected for a Gaussian curve, with mean, standard deviation and X value. A bell curve is a special case of a Gaussian with a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1, so only the X value is variable.

Comment: Then it is probably a Gaussian curve... As i said I've never worked with this curve or graph before :) Heres a link to the email i got [Link](http://pastebin.com/LT11pHC0)

Two images from the mail:
[1](http://japseyz.dk/poto.jpg)
[2](http://japseyz.dk/photo.jpg)